# Python: pd.date_range, not consistent in what it returns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, date, sequence, date-range

Hi could any explain to me why Python behaves in the way below:

```
import pandas as pd
sdate = pd.to_datetime('2020-01-31')
date_range = pd.date_range(start = sdate + pd.DateOffset(months=-3), 
                           end = sdate + pd.DateOffset(months=-1), freq = 'M')
```

the date_range object above returns:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2019-10-31', '2019-11-30', '2019-12-31'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')
```

then if i shift one month forward as per below:

```
sdate = pd.to_datetime('2020-02-29')

date_range = pd.date_range(start = sdate + pd.DateOffset(months=-3), 
                           end = sdate + pd.DateOffset(months=-1), freq = 'M')
```

the date_range object above now returns:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2019-11-30', '2019-12-31'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')
```

why does the second instance only return two dates and the first three dates?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This was an interesting find, the main culprit here is `freq = 'M'` which is for "month end frequency".

## Problem

Problem is mainly that `freq = 'M'` would only shows the **last** days of each month in the period you have, so for the first case we have

```
sdate = pd.to_datetime('2020-01-31')
date_range = pd.date_range(start = sdate + pd.DateOffset(months=-3), 
                           end = sdate + pd.DateOffset(months=-1), freq = 'M')
```

which would evaluate to

```
start = '2019-10-31'
end   = '2019-12-31'
```

so the range between those dates (inclusive) is
`['2019-10-31', '2019-11-30', '2019-12-31']`

now for the second case

```
sdate = pd.to_datetime('2020-02-29')

date_range = pd.date_range(start = sdate + pd.DateOffset(months=-3), 
                           end = sdate + pd.DateOffset(months=-1), freq = 'M')
```

This would evaluate to

```
start = '2019-11-29'
end   = '2020-01-29'
```

so the dates that are THE LAST DAYS OF THE MONTH are `['2019-11-30', '2019-12-31']` because the range ends at `2020-01-29` so `2020-01-31` is not included in the range.

## Solution

Well .. it depends on what you want to achieve, but if your date ranges are on a monthly basis and you don't care about the day, then consider using [MonthEnd](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd.html) as

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd

sdate = pd.to_datetime('2020-02-29')

date_range = pd.date_range(start = sdate + pd.DateOffset(months=-3) + MonthEnd(0), 
                           end = sdate + pd.DateOffset(months=-1) + MonthEnd(0), 
                           freq = 'M')
```

which would give you

```
DatetimeIndex(['2019-11-30', '2019-12-31', '2020-01-31'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')
```

Answer (score 0):

The date_range has a periods parameter.   It is easier to calculate the start date, set the frequency to months, and 3.  The start date can be any day in the month.  date_range returns intervals of time.

```
 sdate=pd.Timestamp('2019-10-01')
 index=pd.date_range(start=sdate,periods=3,freq='M')
 print(index)
```

output:

```
 DatetimeIndex(['2019-10-31', '2019-11-30', '2019-12-31'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')
```